# HEAD merged common ancestors error

Tags: git, github

I wanted to revert my local repo to my last GitHub commit, so I downloaded my GitHub repo and overwrote my local repo with the one I downloaded. I then made changes and tried to commit. When I tried `git push -u origin master`, I got the error message "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally."

Then I did a `git pull origin master` which seemed to auto-merge all of my files except .htaccess, for which I received the error message "Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result."

I then did a force commit `git push -f origin master` and now when I load my index.php in a browser it reads "HEAD merged common ancestors" across the top of the page. When I run `git status` in the terminal it reads "On branch master
You have unmerged paths. (fix conflicts and run "git commit")"

How do I fix conflicts and rid myself of the error message at the top of my page? Repo is at https://github.com/avashije/music

Comment: There is plenty of information on the web about dealing with merge conflicts.  https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=merge%20conflicts%20git

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand and am hoping for a more specific nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a reset using the remote branch.

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/{branch name}
```

similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949804/force-overwrite-of-local-file-with-whats-it-origin-repo).